How to Run Multiple Tomcat Servers in IntelliJ IDE for same Application

I had to run 12 instances of tomcat servers on my Mac for a POC. I initially copied same SpringBoot source code multiple directories and run those in IntelliJ.
Is there a way to run all instances with single application. This minimises code change efforts on diff places and some manual work.

Steps to Run 12 tomcat servers on your Mac​
Have an spring boot instance ready which you want to run locally on 12 different ports.
Goto IntelliJ option > Run (Edit Configuration) Ctrl + Opt + R (Mac shortcut)
Using + sign add new Spring Boot Run Configuration as show below.
Given diff port number in 'VM Option' if you can't find enable to show in IntelliJ setting.
-Dserver.port=8081
this way you can run any number of server instances (I tried 12)
Start one by one and you can call each instance using diff port ex. http://localhost:8081/callDB
That's all you have a common source code running many services locally.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Welcome to SO!
I think you can take many different approaches here.

Run all 12 processes with "one click of the button" in intelliJ.
To do that create a "Compound" Type of Run/Debug Configuration. Your first image already shows that you have all 12 instances defined. Now in the same window press "+" and then select "Compound". Give it a name and add all your instances one by one. Then Run this compound configuration and it will start all the instances.

The first approach still means that you have 12 JVM processes running simultaneously. If you want to run only one JVM application that would expose 12 ports, you can customize the spring boot configuration and create 11 additional Connectors in tomcat (that's the component that waits for incoming connections on some port).



    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Value("${server.port}") int serverPort,
                                                    AdditionalPortConfigProperties conf) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        conf.getPorts().forEach(p -> {  // list of integers - ports to be opened
                Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
                connector.setScheme("http");
                connector.setPort(p.getSrcPort());
                // you can customize the protocol if you wish - set max incoming header size, etc.
                // this line adds a connector to your tomcat configuration
                tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
            }
        });

